# Merge python with python-2.7

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently there are three tags for Python questions:

- [python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python)
- [python-2.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)
- [python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python3)

Whilst I see the reason for the existence of [python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python3), I can't see how [python-2.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) could be useful. I guess it has been created to distinguish between questions about those releases that provide multiple versions of Python, or that do not provide Python 2.7 at all.

However nowadays all supported releases include just [Python 2.7](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7) and nothing else. The only exception is Lucid, which ships with [Python 2.6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.6) and nothing else.

Therefore, I propose the following:

1. Make [python-2.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) a synonym of [python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python).
2. If some questions are about Python 2.6, then use [python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python) together with [10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/10.04).
3. If some questions are about Python 2.7, then just use [python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python).

Answer (score 4):

I am fairly strongly against changing the current situation. It allows users to be specific if they *mean* Python 2 or 3, but also for them to talk generically when the Python version is irrelevant (as it very often is).

Comment: So you want to keep both 'python' and 'python-2.7' and use the former for general Python discussion and the latter for specific Python 2 issues. If this is what you mean, beware that this is not happening right now.

Comment: I hadn't thought about generic python questions.  There is a use case there I suppose.  Upgoat from me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more useful to keep python-2.7 and python3 as master tags and synonimize python with whichever one is default in current LTS.  Then in the future, when it changes, the python tag could be removed(renamed and synonimized) and a new one created for the appropriate version.